# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type ts(2739)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, compiler-errors

I have a function that makes structured data from `rawData` (from API)

```
function makeData(raw:typeof rawData){
    const data:IData = {} // this line throws above error.

    const now = new Date()
    data.createdAt=now.toDateString();
    data.currentUser=raw.name;
    data.uniqueId= raw.id + now.toDateString();

    return data
}
```

As I am making the data, I am using an empty object in the beginning and typing it with IData so that the return value from the function is typed as `IData`. But as mentioned this is throwing error.

```
interface IData {
    createdAt:string;
    currentUser:string;
    uniqueId:string;
}
```

Usage:

```
const {createdAt, currentUser,uniqueId} = makeData(rawData)
```

I tried to remove IData completely then I got the following error.

```
Property 'createdAt' does not exist on type '{}'. // got the same error for other properties as well ( currentUser, uniqueId )
```

Getting the same error(s) on the line where destructing is done.

I got a workaround for now:

```
const data : Record<string,unknown>= {}
```

But this doesn't seem to be more convincing for me.

Is there a better way to type data as IData.

Live [Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jgbwFDKHIJQRYQAmAgmAFwDOYUoA5gNwFEICuUp4AVXrQGTVhyLJuIYAEduEVBVHMQ7PAF88eBAHsQjZFDgB3TNmQBeZPkkg4AWwi1kAIm7CorgDSdCwZXdPAEYAJgBmV01tPBhpBDBgfWQHOABrCHM4AApjE1owAE8ABwhdGCNTLIBKWy59QwosOGQXDGbrHA1kbUk9AzBkEF0TKyGIUfMIbOq-ZCbsADoSMkhqMEthk0WwXSmAZTE1GYkiBbhl3n4wIWhLPMX7J1PCc8XpOQUlaweA5ABqIYjHZ7ciHVQsE69IikMC8EDzZrRbT9Qw4FbkdbeYhXCCCTzeD7yRQUbrWVIZLK5KrNWY6Bq6AA2EEWjN0kIxaxo2J4fDxNwJRK+FGqQA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't define a const of `IData` without specify the data inside of it, instead you can do something like this

```js
function makeData(raw: typeof rawData): IData{
    const now = new Date()
    
    return {
        createdAt: now.toDateString(),
        currentUser: raw.name,
        uniqueId: raw.id + now.toDateString()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here as you are annotating data as `IData`. It expects the object to contain all the required properties. (in this case: createdAt, currentUser, uniqueId)

You can do 2 things.

1:  You can do type assertion.

```
const data = {} as IData.
```

2: Initialise the object with empty values.

```
const data:IData = {
  createdAt:"",
  currentUser:"",
  uniqueId:""
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, helpful. At first, I was confused about why is this a thing typescript is worrying about. So, basically, typescript is saying that I wanted `data` to have the values of type `IData` but you gave me an empty object. Hence either providing values as you did in 2nd or specifying as `IData` (which explicitly does the same I believe) solves the issue. It helps in getting the data type as we assigned.

Answer (score 1):

That's happen because all the propertys inside *IData* are required, so if you define a variable of type *IData* you need to provide it the values

Maybe you can use the UtilityType *Partial* or define what type are you going to return

```
function makeData(raw: typeof rawData): IData { }
```

The comment by @mikrowdev is the best solution for this i think.